# API to get the list of all search providers/engines?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, opera-extension

I am developing an Opera extension. At some moment it allows the user to perform search. Now I use `chrome.tabs.update` with `` { url: `https://google.com/search?q=${encodeURIComponent(query)}`} ``. This is not user friendly. The better approach is to maintain a user-editable list of URLs like `https://google.com/search?q=` or `https://ca.search.yahoo.com/search?p=` in the extension's options page and allow the user to choose between them, but I *really* don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Chromium-based browsers all have user-configurable search engines/providers, and I want to allow the user to choose between them or just use the default. To make that possible, I basically need two API functions:

- a function to get the list of all configured search engines;
- a function to get the default engine.

I didn't find anything similar to my problem in the [API docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index).

BTW, Opera also has an undocumented `chrome.search` function  (Chromium has none), but it always searches via Google regardless of the user's default search engine setting.

Thanks.

PS. If there is a more appropriate place to ask this question, please tell me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I didn't find anything similar to my problem in the API docs.

Because there isn't one, unfortunately.

There is a relevant old [feature request](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=70700) with no real activity.